# GMP timing difference for different integer size;

Tags: c, time, multiplication, gmp

Can anyone tell me how the time taken by differs in GMP if I use operands of different size.
For example : the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define REPEAT 10000

void full_mult(mpz_t r,mpz_t a,mpz_t b)
{
    mpz_t temp;
    mpz_init(temp);

    mpz_mul(r,a,b);
    mpz_add(temp,a,b);
    mpz_sub(a,a,b);
    mpz_mul(temp,temp,a);
    /*the above code 10 more times*/
}

void half_mult(mpz_t r,mpz_t a,mpz_t b)
{
    mpz_t temp;
    mpz_init(temp);

    mpz_mul(r,a,b);
    mpz_add(temp,a,b);
    mpz_sub(a,a,b);
    mpz_mul(temp,temp,a);
    /*the above code then more times*/
}


void main()
{

    long int i;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    gmp_randstate_t state;
    gmp_randinit_mt(state);

    mpz_t a[REPEAT];
    mpz_t b[REPEAT];
    mpz_t a1[REPEAT];
    mpz_t b1[REPEAT];
    mpz_t r[REPEAT];
    mpz_t r1[REPEAT];

    for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++)
    {
        mpz_init(a[i]);mpz_init(b[i]);
        mpz_init(a1[i]);mpz_init(b1[i]);
        mpz_init(r[i]);mpz_init(r1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++)
    {
        mpz_urandomb(a[i],state,128);
        mpz_urandomb(b[i],state,128);

    }

    start=clock();

    for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++)
        half_mult(r[i],a[i],b[i]);

    end=clock();
    printf( "Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );


    for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++)
    {
        mpz_urandomb(a1[i],state,256);
        mpz_urandomb(b1[i],state,256);

    }

    start=clock();

    for(i=0;i<REPEAT;i++)
        full_mult(r1[i],a1[i],b1[i]);

    end=clock();

    printf( "Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

}
```

As you can see I am trying to measure the timing while operating with two types of integers. One with 256 bits and another with 128 bits. But I did not get any conclusive results from this code. Sometimes time for the operations for 128 bits are higher sometimes time for the operations for 256 bits are higher.

Comment: Please use all-uppercase names for macros. And format&indent your code properly.

Comment: Changed the macros. Can you please tell me about the problem in indentation and format. I will be happy to change.

Comment: See your code! If still unsure seach for "C indentation style". Pick one (if possible not too exotic) and use that consistently.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.1.0.pdf) 15.1 section, the library uses different multiplication algorithms for different sizes of operands. Look at thresholds table:

```
| Algorithm | Threshold            |
|-----------|----------------------|
| Basecase  | (none)               |
| Karatsuba | MUL_TOOM22_THRESHOLD |
| Toom-3    | MUL_TOOM33_THRESHOLD |
| Toom-4    | MUL_TOOM44_THRESHOLD |
| Toom-6.5  | MUL_TOOM6H_THRESHOLD |
| Toom-8.5  | MUL_TOOM8H_THRESHOLD |
| FFT       | MUL_FFT_THRESHOLD    |
```

So, since the algorithms are different timings might be different too.

Answer (score 0):

Try a longer sample. I've changed REPEAT to 10000000 and those

```
mpz_t a[REPEAT];
mpz_t b[REPEAT];
mpz_t a1[REPEAT];
mpz_t b1[REPEAT];
mpz_t r[REPEAT];
mpz_t r1[REPEAT];
```

to

```
static mpz_t a[REPEAT];
static mpz_t b[REPEAT];
static mpz_t a1[REPEAT];
static mpz_t b1[REPEAT];
static mpz_t r[REPEAT];
static mpz_t r1[REPEAT];
```

So after 3 runs I got:

```
$ gcc -O2 gmp_bench.c -lgmp
$ time ./a.out             
Number of seconds: 12.689352
Number of seconds: 18.295134
./a.out  34.54s user 1.27s system 99% cpu 35.820 total
$ time ./a.out
Number of seconds: 12.647052
Number of seconds: 17.918326
./a.out  34.08s user 1.35s system 99% cpu 35.426 total
$ time ./a.out
Number of seconds: 12.647854
Number of seconds: 18.106714
./a.out  34.29s user 1.28s system 99% cpu 35.581 total
$
```

By monitoring the execution I've noticed the memory allocated is constantly increasing so allocation overhead may be a higher performance toll than the algorithm itself.

Comment: every mpz_init should have a corresponding mpz_free. Or better yet to measure the multiplication time, the same variables should be reused.